# Unable to Install with Pip Due to Outdated beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda with Python 3 and am trying to install the package cc, which is a requirement for the uber h3 package.

When trying to install in the anaconda command line via:

```
pip install cc
```

I'm getting an error that I'm using an outdated version of beautifulsoup on Python 3 and should use beautifulsoup4 instead. Bs4 IS installed, but it appears the requirements file coming directly to pip selects BeautifulSoup 3.2.1.

How can I override this?

Below is the error I'm getting:

```
Collecting cc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/c0/813dd3de3cda756a7ffc17b50779da0c1ea5de74c9df5e1da2856735c940/cc-0.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cc) (2.22.0)
Collecting BeautifulSoup>=3.2.1
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/f2/6c9f2f3e696ee6a1fb0e4d7850617e224ed2b0b1e872110abffeca2a09d4/BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\wintch3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qgjizksk\\BeautifulSoup\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\wintch3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qgjizksk\\BeautifulSoup\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\wintch3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qgjizksk\BeautifulSoup\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\wintch3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qgjizksk\BeautifulSoup\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\wintch3\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qgjizksk\BeautifulSoup\setup.py", line 3
        "You're trying to run a very old release of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work."<>"Please use Beautiful Soup 4, available through the pip package 'beautifulsoup4'."
                                                                                                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thanks for all and any help!

Comment: can't you just uninstall the old version of "bs"? alternatively, if you want to keep incompatible packages, consider setting up virtual environments for projects

Comment: @OferSadan Best I can tell, I only have beautifulsoup 4.8.1 installed. Both pip and conda list only 4.8.1 installed.

Comment: well something is being used here from the cache. Can you try running `pip` with `--no-cache-dir` ?

Comment: @OferSadan I did already come across that suggestion in searches and the result is the same, unfortunately. :-/

Comment: The package [cc: PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/cc/) shows that it is meant for Python 2.7. Are you using Python 3+? Could that be an issue here?

Comment: @CypherX good point and a keen eye! The cc PyPi page had literally no info so I never scrolled all the way to the bottom to find this. Ultimately I'm trying to install Uber h3 in this environment and it keeps failing and cc apparently is a requirement. Which is odd because h3 supports Python 3, but it appears cc does not...

Comment: @DrCeeDub Take a look at this: [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#the-short-explanation). It might help you in porting library made for Python 2 to Python 3. Especially see [`caniusepython3`](https://pypi.org/project/caniusepython3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see: https://pypi.org/project/cc/#history. The only version was 0.1 released in 2016. It [requires `BeautifulSoup`](https://github.com/ubear/cha/blob/f4f077a4d5fc8452a4d7d1cf3cbbf3360fe59254/setup.py#L18) (not `BeautifulSoup4`).

I very much doubt it's the package that Uber requires. [`h3`](https://pypi.org/project/h3/) really mentions `cc` but it's not a Python package — it's a C compiler! You must have `gcc` or any other C compiler, not that outdated `cc` from PyPI!

Comment: There is a an important part that you missed: it is meant for Python 2.7. I have mentioned that in my solution. In case you down voted my solution, without understanding why (as I was in the process of adding more information then), I would ask you to consider removing the downvote.

Comment: I have left a reference to your solution about the relevant version of BeautifulSoup. Please leave a reference to the fact that it is developed with **Python 2.7** to make your answer complete.

Comment: You are correct, CC simply refers to needing a c-compiler. I got close to installing h3 using this solution, but it continues failing on Windows, which is a known issue with h3. Outside of using a Mac or Linux, I'll stick with MGRS squares instead of Uber's hexagons. Thanks for the help!